# Gihub CLI Error: must be on a branch named differently than "master"

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-cli

I want to sync *staging* branch with *master* using GitHub CLI tool (`gh`). So I am on the *master* branch locally and I run this command:

```
gh pr create -b staging -t "master -> staging"
```

but I receive this error:

> must be on a branch named differently than "master"

I am still new to GitHub CLI and I am not sure why I need to have a branch different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) uses the currently checked out branch as the branch containing the commits for your pull request (*`head`*). Consequently, your command tries to create a PR from *master* to *master* which is not possible.

You can use the `head` and `base` parameters to create the desired PR (merging *master* into *staging*) like this:

```sh
gh pr create --head master --base staging
```

If you are currently on the `master` branch, you can omit the `head` parameter:

```sh
gh pr create --base staging
```

*Both ways result in this:*
[image: result]

---

*Sidenote: In your question you are using `-b staging` which is short for `--body staging`. The correct shorthand for `--base staging` would be `-B staging`.*

Comment: If the 'pr create' uses the currently checked-out branch as head, why did it work when I specified the head as master but didn't work when I was already checked out to master?

Comment: @ZaidAfaneh I don't think that specifying the `head` parameter actually solved your problem but the correct usage of the `--base` parameter. I just extended my answer a bit to include this. Note the difference between the shorthand for the body (`-b`) and for the base (`-B`).